# Django admin select all checkbox not working

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I'm using Django 2.2.7 with python 3.8 in pipenv 2018.11.26. In my django admin i can't select all items checkbox (see pic below) in list of model objects and not see datepicker with actions "now" & "today".

[image: Trouble with django admin select all checkbox]

Comment: The exact same issue re-appears in Django 4.1 and this time there is no FORM_RENDERER on default settings.py !

Comment: Having the same issue on django 4.2. Have you found a fix?

Answer (score 2):

I found a place that causes this problem.
In my settings.py:

```py
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
```

This setting override all widgets and his templates and therefore not work some of widgets in my django admin.